# convert dynamic drawing page in Flash into .dxf or .dwg format

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dwg, dxf

I want to convert my  dynamic Drawing (that I created in a Flash Dialog using AS 3) into the .DXF and .DWG format.Is there any way by which I can give the export functionality on the flash page so that the dynamic drawing that created in flash code will export into .DXF and .DWG format.

Please Help

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create the binary files with ByteArray (it could be quite hard, but maybe there are libraries for it already), but if it's only for you, I would print it as PDF or PostScript (Adobe Distiller, etc...) and then convert the vectors to DXF/DWG format via Illustrator or similar. You could also try with [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) to export as PDF...

Comment: Hi,

Very Thanks for the instant reply. can you please tell me if there is any tool command line or any ,net library that can convert PDf to DXF/DWG format.

If possible can you please give me any example for this((print it as PDF or PostScript (Adobe Distiller, etc...) and then convert the vectors to DXF/DWG format via Illustrator or similar))

Very Thanks!!

Comment: If you import a vector-based PDF (or a PostScript file) in Illustrator you can export it (File > Export...) as DXF, DWG and many other formats. There are many ways to get the vector PDF, the simplest beeing right-click on the Flash Player > Print (you can also use the PrintJob class within flash). Once in the printing dialog you can use either Adobe Distiller (a virtual printer that prints to PDF files and comes with Acrobat PRO) or in OSX use "Save to PDF" in the printing dialog.

Comment: Hi,
I have created the PDF using AlivePDF. i have not used illustrator before. Can you please tell me if there is any possibilities that i can convert PDf into DXF/DWG format by using illustrator(through code) or any other way.

Comment: I have tried converting PDF into DXF format using Illustrator.Its output is 2 files 1 is .dxf and otherone is .png and if i delete that png file then .dxf file is coming blank in viewer.I think that .dxf file is internally calling that png file. Is this correct?

Comment: the pdf that you are generating is probably not vector based, and the png is the image within the pdf. Having your SWF file open, try right-click > print... then choose "Adobe PDF" from your printers and try with that... Are you on OSX or Windows?

Comment: Thanks Cay for reply!!
I have tried this by creating PDF using Print dialog but this PDF also create PNG file with dxf/dwg format.Is there any other way for this. I am on Windows XP server.
Thanks for your help again.